# Traveling to London and then Amsterdam next month. My U.S. passport expires in 5 months. Will I have an issue traveling?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, passports, international-travel, irish-citizens

I have an Irish passport as well so I was wondering if I can just use that to enter the countries.

Comment: When does your Irish passport expire?

Comment: @MikeHarris good point.  The Irish passport should be valid for the entire stay in the Netherlands, although a valid US passport would satisfy the ID law if the Irish passport expires.  I believe an Irish citizen does not need to have a valid passport (or any ID) to remain in the UK, so the passport expiring in the UK would only be a problem if the Netherlands portion of the trip is subsequent to the UK portion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As an Irish citizen you have a right of free movement in other European Union countries.  You can indeed use your Irish passport; there's generally no good reason not to.

You need to use you US passport when you enter the US, though, so be certain to bring it with you.

Comment: To add to this, with an Irish passport you'll be able to use the EU / EEA line at airports in the EU, which usually moves a lot faster than the "rest of the world" line.